# Обрезка внешней зоны размытия элемента SVG фильтром Гаусса

Tags: css, svg

Есть простой SVG код, который рисует две прямоугольные рамки с закругленными краями. Первая рамка размыта фильтром Гаусса. Вторая рамка  нет, и она по тем же координатам.

Как обрезать размытую часть первой рамки, которая располагается снаружи второй рамки?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200" version="1.1">
     <defs>
      <filter id="fg152620" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7" />
      </filter>
     </defs>
      
     <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#fg152620)"/>      
     <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

У меня есть решение с использование clipPath, но оно требует повторного указания координат x,y... Объектов много, и они разного размера. Хотелось бы обойтись без указания координат, а за основу брать вторую рамку. Как бы обрезать её background-clip по border-box.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200" version="1.1">
     <defs>
      <filter id="fg152620" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7" />
      </filter>
      
      <clipPath id="cut152620"  >
        <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" />
      </clipPath>
     </defs>
      
     <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#fg152620)" clip-path="url(#cut152620)"/>
     <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
     
</svg>
```

Comment: ещё показали бы желаемое поведение ..было бы круто

Comment: Согласен, просто я не нашел как :) Я тут совсем недавно. В Вашем примере ниже есть кнопка Выполнить код. Очень удобно. Я обязательно почитаю как на этом сайте делать так же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот на таком способе я пока что остановился. Использую clip-path="inset(0px round 10px)"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" version="1.1">
 <defs>
  <filter id="fg152620" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" />
  </filter>
 </defs>

 <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="210" height="110" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#fg152620)" clip-path="inset(0px round 10px)" />
 <rect x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="210" height="110" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант в Firefox работает не так, как в Chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/voffa.png Рассмотрите [вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1121178/28748), который работает во всех браузерах одинаково

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  https://prnt.sc/sbz2sh почему у вас не так отображается ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Скриншот снят  FF  75.0 (64-битный)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  https://prnt.sc/sbz773, проверьте наличие обновлений для FF

Comment: @MaximLensky Обновил до 76 версии Ничего не изменилось- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP1eJ.png

Comment: @Alexandr_TT почему так ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Не знаю Максим, наверное надо попросить кого нибудь ещё посмотреть в FF со свежей версией 76.0

Comment: Печально получилось, FF весьма распространен. Завтра поеду на работу пробовать свой пример. Там как раз есть FF. Спасибо за предупреждение.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, фильтр `feGaussianBlur` использовался для придания кнопке объема, но при этом появилось необходимость обрезать внешнюю зону размытия элемента SVG фильтром Гаусса.

Предлагаю для обрезки внешней стороны размытия, рассмотреть вариант с использованием фильтра `feComposite`.

Фильтры `feSpecularLighting`, `feDistantLigh` служат для создания большей реалистичности 3D эффекта.

**Создав один раз такую комбинацию фильтров, Вы можете использовать её для большого количества SVG объектов без учёта их габаритных размеров.**

```css
.btn {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#919191;
stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterUp">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="45"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
   
 </defs>
 <rect id="back" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#d3d3d3" />
    <rect class="btn"   x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="210" height="110"  /> 
 
</svg>
```

### Пример визуального эффекта нажатия кнопки при наведении

Меняется всего один параметр `elevation` в фильтре отвечающем за направление света

`<feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/>`

```css
.btn {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#919191;
stroke-width:2;
}
.btn:hover {
filter:url(#filterDown);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#888888;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterUp">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="45"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="filterDown">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>
 <rect id="back" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#d3d3d3" />
    <rect class="btn"   x="20" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="210" height="110"  /> 
   <rect class="btn"   x="250" y="20" rx="10" ry="10" width="210" height="110"  /> 

</svg>
```

**Пример эффекта нажатия круглой кнопки**

```css
.btn {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#919191;
stroke-width:2;
}
.btn:hover {
filter:url(#filterDown);
fill:#919191;
stroke:#888888;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterUp">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="45"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="filterDown">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>
  <rect id="back" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#d3d3d3" /> 
    
   <circle class="btn" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" /> 
      <circle class="btn" cx="250" cy="100" r="50" />

</svg>
```

**Пример эффекта нажатия двухцветной круглой кнопки**

```css
.btn {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:red;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:3;
}
.btn:hover {
filter:url(#filterDown);
fill:green;
stroke:green;
}
.btn2 {
filter:url(#filterUp);
fill:green;
stroke:green;
stroke-width:2;
}
.btn2:hover {
filter:url(#filterDown);
fill:dodgerblue;
stroke:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterUp">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="45"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>

    <filter id="filterDown">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" result="blur1"/>
      <feSpecularLighting result="specOut" in="blur1" specularConstant="1.2" specularExponent="12" lighting-color="#fff">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="225" elevation="145"/> 
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="result"/>
      <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
 
 </defs>
  <rect id="back" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#d3d3d3" /> 
    
   <circle class="btn" cx="100" cy="100" r="25" /> 
     <circle class="btn2" cx="200" cy="100" r="25" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Очень просто и красиво. Большое спасибо за пример, беру на вооружение. Да, действительно я использую фильтр для придания объема. И когда в очередной раз буду делать что то своего стиля, обязательно использую предложенный Вами способ.

Comment: В этот раз мне нужно было максимально повторить стиль элементов, уже присутствующих на сайте. Более чем уверен, что там именно фильтр feGaussianBlur использовался. Результаты получаются идентичные. Только размытая рамка ещё смещена на пиксель вниз. Об этом в теме вопроса не писал, чтобы лишний раз никого не запутывать.

Comment: @СергейКазаков Отлично, кто же будет спорить, если ваше решение больше подходит Вам для вашего сайта. Надо только устранить неработоспособность в Firefox. Моё решение универсально, работает везде. Так что можете использовать его в своих будущих разработках.

Comment: Уже использую! Добавил себе на сайт Ваш код в качестве примера, чтобы потом заново не вспоминать тему. Работает превосходно. Мне даже больше нравится чем то что есть.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть так ?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240" height="150" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 -1 242 152" style="border-radius: 10px;">
 <defs>
  <filter id="fg152620" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
   <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="7" />
  </filter>
 </defs>

 <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#fg152620)"/>    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="240" height="150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: К сожалению тут мы тоже повторно указываем размеры в строке viewBox="-1 -1 242 152" style="border-radius: 10px;

Comment: В своей задаче я сильно ограничен в этом, и могу оттолкнуться только от самих рамок и размеров rect

Comment: @СергейКазаков viewBox это не строке

Comment: Я имел виду строку кода, где используется viewBox. В ней ширина и длинна зависят от прямоугольника rect. Как Вы думайте, решение с clip-path="inset(0px round 10px)" допустимое? При условии что в коде много рамок rect, и они разного размера.

Comment: @СергейКазаков просто проверьте это в хром edge ff - если работает значит нормальное решение